# How to add double window trim (toolbar) in efxclipse e4?

Tags: e4, efxclipse

Is it possible to set a double toolbar in efxclipse e4 (both with side: top; one below second)?

```
<trimBars>
      <children xsi:type="menu:ToolBar"/>
</trimBars>
<trimBars>
      <children xsi:type="menu:ToolBar"/>
</trimBars>
```

[image: Application.e4xmi example]

Comment: Have you tried it? What happens?

Comment: Second WindowTrim covering first WindowTrim unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it can't be render now:
[answer from e(fx)clipse forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1065275&goto=1690841&#msg_1690841)

Regards